# Why has my original Ubuntu 19.04 Ubuntu Budgie loading screen?

Tags: boot, ubuntu-budgie

I want to ask you why I have on my newly instaled Ubuntu 19.04 Ubuntu Budgie loading screen. Firstly it booted with normal Ubuntu loading screen, but after two days it started booting with loading screen characteristic for Ubuntu Budgie. Can somebody answer why?
Thank everyone!

Comment: Do you mean the screen at boot up AKA plymouth? Run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and  Ubuntu-logo Plymouth

Comment: Do you have installed any budgie related packages ? plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-logo and plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-text should be responsible of this.